# PHP Error with constants

Tags: php, error-handling, constants

I have several files that are includes as follow:

index.php

```
require("database.php");
require("header.php");
require("template.php");
require("footer.php");
```

database.php

```
require("constants.php");
class connect{
 public function connect(){
 mysql_connect(LOCALHOST,USER,PASS);
}
}
```

constants.php

```
define('LOCALHOST','localhost');
define("USER","username");
define("PASS","password");
define("PRICE1","10.00");
define("PRICE2","11.00");
define("PRICE3","12.00");
define("PRICE4","13.00");
```

template.php

```
*html code*
*ajax code*
*ajax output*
```

** it is the ajax load that outputs the error
load.php (ajax get)

```
require(database.php);
then html code
```

which outputs the error:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant PRICE1 - assumed 'PRICE1' in web/site/files/template.php on line 34

anyone got any sugestions as i am stuck as to why the constant has not been called as i have defined it

Let me clarify the question:

The constants is included into the database.php which the database.php uses the constants to connect and also works fine.
When the database.php is required into the template.php there is the error showing. The question is why is it not passing the constants through when the constants are working on the database.php

---

If i run load.php the error message is in there still
but i am again running the database in there which is working but none of the constants can be called from load.php

See the full load.php code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(isset($_GET['label']) && $_GET['type'] == "yes" && $_GET['dif'] == "label"){

    try{
        require_once("../classes/database.php");
        $db = new MySQL();
        $connection = $db->connect();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `label` WHERE id=?";
        $result = $db->prepare($sql,array($_GET['label']),$connection);
        if(!$result){
            throw new Exception("Error: ");
        }
        $number = $result['personalisedlines'];

        for($i=0;$i<$number;$i++){
            echo "<label>Line ".($i+1)."</label>\n\r<br />\n\r";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='label_price' value='".PRICE1."' />";
            echo "<input type='text' name='field".$i."' />\n\r<br />\n\r";
        }
        }   catch(Exception $e){
            throw $e;
        }
}
if($_GET['type'] == "yes" && $_GET['dif'] == "engraving"){
    echo "<br />\n\r<label>Engraved Message</label>\n\r<br />\n\r";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='engraving_price' value='".PRICE2."' />";
    echo "<textarea cols='30' rows='10' name='personalisedbox' row='10'></textarea>\n\r<br />\n\r";
}

if($_GET['type'] == "yes" && $_GET['dif'] == "printed"){
    echo "<br />\n\r<label>Printed Message</label>\n\r<br />\n\r";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='printed_price' value='".PRICE3."' />";
    echo "<textarea cols='30' rows='10' name='personalisedbox' row='10'></textarea>\n\r<br />\n\r";
}

if($_GET['type'] == "yes" && $_GET['dif'] == "flutes"){
    echo "<br />\n\r<label>Engraved Message</label>\n\r<br />\n\r";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='engraving_price' value='".PRICE4."' />";
    echo "<textarea cols='30' rows='10' name='personalisedflutes' row='10'></textarea>\n\r<br />\n\r";
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you working with `namespace`s ? Do you have the `use` keyword somewhere ? Are the `define`s being set or called inside a class or function?

Comment: no they are included for the use of the database.php but not edited or changed in anyway these four constants are not used in the database.php also no namespace or use is not used anywhere in my code

Comment: Which part of the error message specifically didn't you understand? I mean it's pretty clear isn't it? No constant named `PRICE1` is defined (PHP will use the string `"PRICE1"` instead then). What do you want to ask about *specifically*? And **no**, *you have **not** defined it [the constant]*. See the error message, it tells you that you have **not defined it**. PHP does not lie to you, it's too dumb to lie.

Comment: Which file are you accessing? You will get this error if you try to load template.php directly.

Comment: Maybe the code in `constants.php` is not executed? I mean it is in block comment, in some `if` statement or after `return` etc.

Comment: @hakre, did you even read the question?

Comment: Did you include *constants.php* in your template, either through another include or in the file itself?

Comment: Did you include index.php in template.php?

Comment: @nl-x: Which ***question***? I've read the code and it clearly shows that the constant is not defined. Same as the error tells OP.

Comment: @VinothBabu he included template.php in index.php

Comment: let me clarify the template.php has database.php required the database has the constants.php clarified and connects to the database (which it does sucessfully) the database.php uses these constants. I don't understand why it will not pass the constants to the template.php

Comment: Do you have the opening <?php tag at the head of your included files?

Comment: yes the <?php ?> tags are included. Also so people didn't understand if the constants where not included the database would not work. which it does

Comment: Show us your complete files, not excerpts. Your description does not match the actual contents. There's too much guessing going on here.

Comment: might be abit better now

Comment: Show your includes in your `template.php` file so people can double-check.

Comment: Looking at your Edited question: Since you CAN use the constants inside your database class, I therefore think that your `define`s are done INSIDE the database class. Try using `connect::PRICE1` instead...

Comment: the template.php doesn't have any includes as this is done in the index.php

Comment: if you look at the way my database.php is i have got the require before the class. and the constants.php isn't a class either

Comment: also if i echo PRICE1 in the template this is correct and outputs

Comment: which php script is being called by the AJAX request? (Use something like firebug to know for sure.) And are all the .php's in the same directory.

Comment: i have just posted the code now for the load.php which is not in the same directory but it is using the database which is running fine

Comment: oh but the constants.php is in the same directory as the database.php

Comment: @LiamSorsby Is there by any chance another `constants.php` inside the directory that contains `load.php` ?

Comment: sorted. the load.php had the require in an if statement as above. Thankyou everyone for there help

Comment: @LiamSorsby I wanted to say that ! But you said the Database was working in the AJAX! And that is also in the if statement

Comment: yeah it was but there was only a database connection in that if statement. was a stupid error. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't yet know why the require is not catching on, with the correct scope. Maybe the way you put things in your question isn't exactly in the same order as in your situation? Please show **more** code.

But what you can do is:

Change `require` into `require_once` ...

Now put copy/paste the `require_once()` line into each php file where you wish to use the constants. PHP will make sure the require is done just once, so you won't get any errors about redefining the constants.

Comment: i have edited the code above as this is the ajax code output that is where the code is which only has one require file (which i have changed to require_once() just to make sure and that is to the database.php which has the constants.php included

Answer (score 0):

Include `constants.php` in `templates.php`.

Comment: Why would this help? `constants.php` is required inside `database.php` already

Comment: exactly it is included in the database.php why does it not pass the constants through?